# CSS - Button with down arrow, need it to point up on :hover

Tags: html, css

Having trouble with below:
I have a button that has an arrow pointing down in the description.
I need the arrow to point up as I hover over the button (or any of the contents within the button).
I can only seem to get the arrow to point up when I hover over the arrow, but not the button.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn" for="#updown_up"> Dropdown<i class="arrow updown" id="updown_up"></i></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.updown {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.updown:hover {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

Comment: Just try this `.dropbtn:hover .updown {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}` and remove `.updown:hover` from your CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which uses a child selector:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.updown {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropbtn .updown {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" for="#updown_up"> Dropdown<i class="arrow updown" id="updown_up"></i></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```